# How to remove bad lanes in ImageJ Westernblot analysis

Tags: proteins, western-blot, imagej

I use ImageJ to do an analysis of a Westernblot Image.

If everything goes as wanted the workflow is fine. But if I do something wrong creating a lane there is no undo for a lane and also no way to remove all lanes that I can find.

How do I get back to my original image or undo a lane creation?

I'm using 1.49e on Mac OS

Comment: You question is slightly unclear! do you mean how to crop out a WB lane in an image or how to remove a lane from the middle of an image if it did not produce the results you were looking for?

Comment: So you chose a lane by accident which you don't want to include in your analysis?

Comment: Yeah I created a lane with the wrong size and I can't find a way to undo the creation to recreate the lane correctly.

Answer (score 7):

ImageJ doesn't have a feature to remove individual lanes. But that shouldn't be a problem. All you have to do is **draw the first lane correctly** (I'm referring to size). Then press <kbd>1</kbd>. Now, while the selection is still... selected, click inside it, but not on the number (where the cursor becomes hand), and drag it where you want the next lane. And press <kbd>2</kbd>. And so on. Draw all your lanes.

Now, if you misplaced a lane, click the rectangle selection tool, then click on the lane number while the cursor is a hand. It will be selected. If you're having troubles with this, use the shortcuts <kbd>Ctrl+1</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+2</kbd> or the menu **Analyze** - **Gels** - **Select Previous/Next Lane** to select between lanes. The cursor turns to normal. Click anywhere inside the lane and drag it on the right place.

If the first lane was bad and you want to remove all lanes, just go to **Analyze**, **Gels** and click on **Reset**.

Comment: Hi Cornelius the menu contains only select first and next lane. There is no way to move between lanes. And for me it is also not possible to select lanes with the mouse. But pressing [ctrl/command] [1] removes all lanes but the first and lets me recreate the lanes. That helps a lot.